# How do I find the spectrum of a ring?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

What is $Spec R$ where $R$ is the integers modulo $6$? More generally, what are the techniques to find the *spectrum* of any commutative ring? (I would also be interested in the non-commutative case but this is secondary)

Comment: So, you're asking what the prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z} / 6 \mathbb{Z}$ are?

Comment: $Spec R$ is the set of all prime ideals in $R$. In your case this is trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (prime) ideals in a quotient such as $\mathbf Z/6\mathbf Z$  are in bijection with the (prime) ideals of $\mathbf Z$ that contain the ideal $6\mathbf Z $, i.e. with the prime divisors of $6$:
$$\operatorname{Spec}R=\bigl\{2\mathbf Z/6\mathbf Z,3\mathbf Z/6\mathbf Z\}.$$

Comment: Ahh yes, thank you. Are there any general techniques when the ring in question is not a quotient?

Comment: There's also the case of rings of fractions $S^{-1}R$, where $S$ is a multiplicatively closed subset of $R$. This includes the case of localisations of $R$ at prime ideals.